# Get the component (of which I don't know the instance class) from the one passed to <ng-content>

Tags: angular, components, parent-child, wrapper, ng-content

I have this component:

```
@Component({
selector: 'my-container',
template: `
    <div class="my-container">
        <div #wrapper class="my-container-body">
            <ng-content></ng-content>
        </div>
        <div class="my-container-footer"></div>
    </div>  
`
})
export class MyContainer implements AfterViewInit {
    @ViewChild('wrapped') item: ElementRef;

    ngAfterViewInit() {
        console.log('wrapped item is: ' + this.item.nativeElement);
    }
}
```

For example they can use my wrapped in the following way:

```
<my-container>
    <some-component></some-component>
<my-container>
```

As you can see I can access to wrapped component, using `@ViewChild`.
Instead I would like to access to the component instance that is passed to `<ng-content></ng-content>`, but maybe it couldn't work because I don't know what is the right type to use since I don't know what kind of component is passed to my wrapper.
The same occurs with `@ContentChild`.

Am I doing something wrong? How to access to properties and methods of the passed component that could be any component?

Comment: what would you like to do with that component reference in MyContainer?

Comment: My component is a wrapper for any form element. So I want to access to the form control of the passed component, that could be a custom one or an element with a directive.

Comment: could you try `@ContentChild(NgControl)`?

Comment: It does the trick! Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you need something exact from the content component (in your case it is a NgControl) it would be more logical to query for control, not the whole component.

```
@ContentChild(NgControl) wrappedControl: NgControl;
```

Comment: I wrote it like this: `@ContentChild(NgControl) wrappedComponent: FormControlName | FormControlDirective;`